# Need lowest price in each region in a mysql query

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying to write up a query for wordpress which will give me all the `post_id`'s with the lowest `fromprice` field for each `region`.  Now the trick is these are custom fields in wordpress, and due to such, the information is stored row based, so there is no `region` and `fromprice` columns.

So the data I have is (but of course containing a lot more rows):

```
Post_ID | Meta_Key  | Meta_Value
1       | Region    | Location1
1       | FromPrice | 150
2       | Region    | Location1
2       | FromPrice | 160
3       | Region    | Location2
3       | FromPrice | 145
```

The query I am endeavoring to build should return the post_id of the "lowest priced" matching post grouped by each region with results like:

```
Post_ID | Region | From Price
1       | Location1 | 150
3       | Location2 | 145
```

This will allow me to easily iterate the post_id's and print the required information, in fact, I would be just happy with returning post_id's if the rest is harder, I can then fetch the information independently if need be.

Thanks a lot, tearing my hair out over this one; don't often have to think about shifting results on their side from row based to column based that often, but this time I need it!

So you get an idea of the table structure I have, you can use the below as a guide.  I thought I had this, but it turned out yes, this query prints out each distinct region WITH the lowest from price found attached to that post in the region, but the post_id is completely incorrect.  I don't know why, it seems to be just getting the first result of the post_id and using that.

```
SELECT  pm.post_id, 
        pm2.meta_value as region, 
        MIN(pm.meta_value) as price 
FROM `wp_postmeta` pm 
inner join `wp_postmeta` pm2 
  on pm2.post_id = pm.post_id 
     AND pm2.meta_key = 'region'
     AND pm.meta_key = 'fromprice'
group by region
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest changing `MIN(pm.meta_value)` in your query to be `MIN(CAST(pm.meta_value AS DECIMAL))`. Meta_value is a character field, so your existing query will be returning the minimum string value, not the minimum numeric value; for example, "100" will be deemed to be lower than "21".

EDIT - amended CAST syntax.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know if it would infer this procedure or not, that will be a great help.

Comment: Hmm, when I do that I receive an error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'pm.meta_value AS DECIMAL) FROM `wp_postmeta` pm inner join `wp_po' at line 1]

Comment: Oops - looks like I had the CAST syntax wrong. Try the amended version.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to figure out without being able to execute the query, but would it help to just change your group by to:

```
group by pm.post_id, region
```

Comment: I just tried that, now I get every post; which would make sense, as if I start grouping by `post_id`, these are unique every time, so of course I will get an individual group for each one.